# multiplication of two binary numbers

Tags: coq, implementation

I need to do the function that multiplicates two binary numbers represented by a list of booleans.
Here what I wrote :

```
Fixpoint brmul_r (x y res: list bool): list bool := 
 match x,y,res with
 |x,y,res-> if value x >0 then res else if (value x) mod 2 = 0 then brmul_r ((value x/2) (value y*2) (badd res y)) 
 else brmul_r (x y*2 res)
end.
```

but it doesn't work.. what should I do?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with that code:

1. Syntax error: you want to use `=>` instead of `->` inside the `match`.
2. Actually, you are not taking advantage of the patter matching, so you can remove it entirely and start your definition with `if ...`.
3. Then Coq complains that `_ > _` has type `Prop`. You need to use the boolean version `_ <? _` instead, and the same for the equality later: `_ =? _` instead of `_ = _`.
4. In `brmul_r ((value x/2) (value y*2) (badd res y))`, the outer brackets are not supposed to be there; `brmul_r` is supposed to receive three arguments, not one argument, and similarly for `brmul_r (x y*2 res)`
5. What do you mean by `value x/2`? Is it `value (x / 2)` or `(value x) / 2`? The former does not type-check unless you redefined the `_ / _` notation to work over lists of booleans. But the latter has type `nat`, and `brmul_r` expects something of type `list bool`, so it doesn't work either. A similar observation holds for `value y*2`.
6. This is not something Coq complains about yet (the problem in 5 would have to be solved first), but it will not be clear for Coq that your definition terminates, since you are using `brmul_r` to define `brmul_r` and feeding it non-structurally decreasing arguments. In fact, you even feed it *increasing* arguments in the final branch (I'm talking about `brmul_r x y*2 res`).

---

So what should one do? Convincing Coq that the function terminates is the real issue here, the rest is just confusion over syntax. Since this is a function on lists, it should recurse on the list structure, so it should have the following basic shape (I am assuming the context of `Require Import List. Import ListNotations.`):

```
Fixpoint brmul_r (xs ys : list bool) : list bool :=
  match xs with
  | [] => (* TODO *)
  | hd :: tl => (* TODO *)
  end.
```

Assuming the first element of the list is the least significant bit, it will be useful to match on it as well, so the structure becomes:

```
Fixpoint brmul_r (xs ys : list bool) : list bool :=
  match xs with
  | [] => (* TODO *)
  | false :: tl => (* TODO *)
  | true :: tl => (* TODO *)
  end.
```

Now the goal is to express the product of `false :: tl` with `ys` when we already know the product of `tl` with `ys`. Translating to numbers (for intuition's sake), we want to find `(2 * (value tl)) * (value ys)` when we already know how to compute `(value tl) * (value ys)`. Putting it like this, it becomes clear that we just need to duplicate the result of the latter. Going back to our list representation, we observe that duplicating corresponds to preppending `false`, so we can update our definition as follows:

```
Fixpoint brmul_r (xs ys : list bool) : list bool :=
  match xs with
  | [] => (* TODO *)
  | false :: tl => false :: brmul_r tl ys
  | true :: tl => (* TODO *)
  end.
```

Now you can use the same reasoning to complete the function.

---

For the future:

1. Please include the necessary context. In this case it would be the modules you imported and the custom defined functions such as `value`.
2. It might be useful to follow a Coq tutorial to help with all the syntax issues and with the intuitions behind recursive and functional programming. [Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/) is very good. There are also [others](https://coq.inria.fr/documentation).
3. There is now a [dedicated Stack Exchange site](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/) for Proof Assistant-related questions.